# package.xml api version changed to 28 today?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, ide

Today my local version of package.xml was changed from 27 to 28.

I am using force.com ide  version28.0.1.201309101331

I did not do it myself, can you think of anything that would have triggered this change?

Is there a setting in the sandbox itself that would cause this?

thanks
Joel

Comment: I would of expected it to change to 29. My understanding is that when the org that you are refreshing from is upgraded, i.e. to Winter '14, the API number in the package.xml will change to match after doing a refresh.

Comment: Is this in Eclipse or Ant?

Comment: eclipse, clarified question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just recently updated your Force.com IDE you may have seen a dialog with something like:

> Project was created in an older version of the Force.com IDE and must
>   be upgraded to be used with Summer '13.  You will not be able to save
>   or refresh files in this project from the server until you upgrade it.
>   To upgrade, use the upgrade wizard by right-clicking on the project in
>   Package Explorer and choosing Force.com > Upgrade Project.

I think when the project is upgraded it changes the package.xml version to match the version supported by the Force.com IDE. So in your case it changed it from 27 to 28 (Summer '13).